# Is it best practice to write an ivar that accommodates for each property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I was wondering if it is best practice to do something like this. I heard it is from someone, but I am not too sure. Even though I am using the property only.

.m

```
  @interface AllViewController (){
   NSArray *tableArray;
    }
   @property (nonatomic, retain)  NSArray *tableArray;
   @end;
```

Comment: Negative.  Use the property only except in cases where you have a clear reason not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

1. It is not required. You gain no benefit from it.
2. You should avoid ivars in `@interface {}`. Private ivars should be in `@implementation {}` and you should avoid protected ivars and absolutely no public ivars.

Also in your example, you may have two ivars, `tableArray` and `_tableArray` which generated by auto`@synthesize`. Someone may surprised that the values of `tableArray` and `self.tableArray` are different.

Comment: I don't believe there is any difference between putting private ivar declarations in the class extension block or the implementation block.

Comment: @rmaddy I missed that. The only difference is that class extension block can be in separate .h file and shared by others. But I agree most of the time it is fine to put ivars there.

Comment: No, the class extension block only goes in a .m file, not a .h so it is not shared by anyone.

Comment: Correct, I do know for a fact you don't put anything in .h unless it is being used by another class.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface AllViewController   
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSArray *tableArray;
@end;
```

This is all you need.

You can access tableArray using self.tableArray or _tableArray

Comment: Your last sentence isn't really correct. You can only access the `tableArray` property by using `self.tableArray`. Using `_tableArray` does not access the property. It bypasses the property and directly uses the ivar. Depending on the implementation of the property methods, this can be a very important distinction.

Comment: you are correct. I mean't you use both of them but I didn't say they mean the same